# Slow transitions of MatAccordion component in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: angular, typescript, internet-explorer, angular-material2

In my Angular application I have a form with a long list of checkboxes. To make the interface more clear, the options are presented in a dialog (using Material's `MatDialog`) and further separated into different categories by an accordion component (`MatAccordion`).

The user can navigate through the categories by "previous" and "next" buttons at the bottom of each `MatExpansionPanel`, just as in the [example in the Material documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/examples).

```
<mat-accordion [formGroup]="formGroup" class="aligned-accordion-descriptions">

  <mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="step === 0" (opened)="setStep(0)" (afterExpand)="scrollToCurrentStep()">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>Options</mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>{{categories.cat1.selected}} / {{categories.cat1.totalItems}}</mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>

    <div class="flex-row" style="align-items: baseline;">
      <h2>Category 1</h2><span>Category 1 caption</span>
    </div>

    <div class="options-list">
      <checkbox-input findControlByName="OPTION1"><span>Option 1</span></checkbox-input>
      (...)
    </div>

    (...)

    <mat-action-row>
      <button type="button" mat-button (click)="prevStep()" disabled>Previous</button>
      <button type="button" mat-button (click)="selectAllFlagsOfCategory('cat1')">Select All</button>
      <button type="button" mat-button (click)="nextStep()">Next</button>
    </mat-action-row>

  </mat-expansion-panel>

  (...)

</mat-accordion>
```

This works well in Chrome and Firefox, but in **Internet Explorer 11** - which I unfortunately have to support - there is always a **short delay after clicking a "Next" button** before the next `MatExpansionPanel` is expanded.

Deactivating the animation (see below) did not help much, nor did removing the code that observes changes on the checkboxes, which might have an impact on performance.

```
<mat-accordion [formGroup]="formGroup" [@.disabled]="true" class="aligned-accordion-descriptions">
```

When I open the example from the documentation in IE, it seems alright. I have the impression that the delay depends on the height of the `MatExpansionPanel` that is expanded - when it has 10 or more checkboxes it seems to be much slower in comparison to short panels.

Is there any way to improve the user experience for IE users without interfering too much with the experience for the majority?

Comment: About the "checkbox-input" elements, whether it is your custom directive. Can you share more details about that. Since you are using Angular-Material, I think you could try to use the Material's [mat-checkbox](https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/overview) control.   *I have the impression that the delay depends on the height of the MatExpansionPanel that is expanded - when it has 10 or more checkboxes it seems to be much slower in comparison to short panels.* As for this speculation, you could try to change the layout and decrease the height of the panel.

Comment: The "checkbox-input" is basically just a wrapper for mat-checkbox which adds some logic. Replacing the elements by mat-checkbox did not make any difference. Changing the layout or reducing the amount of checkboxes is not an option either. The layout already is pretty slim.